# How does Mathematica evaluate these sum and integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, summation

How does Mathematica internally evaluate the following (interrelated) sum and integral, and how does it do the subsequent simplification? (I mean, based on what mathematical facts?)

```
Sum[1 /(4^(3 m))  Binomial[2 m, m]^3, {m, 0, ∞}]
```

> π/Gamma[3/4]^4

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - Sin[t]^2 Sin[s]^2], {s, 0, Pi/2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

> EllipticK[1/2]^2

```
EllipticK[1/2]^2/((8 Gamma[5/4]^2)/Sqrt[π])^2 // FullSimplify
```

> 1/4

I did not find these details in tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.

Comment: `FunctionExpand[EllipticK[1/2]]` yields an expression in terms of gamma functions, which presumably gets used in the simplification.

Comment: @J.M.: Thank you for your comment. My question then, concerning the simplification, is this: how does  ```FunctionExpand[EllipticK[1/2]]``` do it? As I wrote, I am interested in the **mathematical facts** on which these interrelated results are based.

Comment: I would guess the results of [Borwein](https://doi.org/10.1093/imanum/12.4.519) and [Zucker](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100053731) are somehow involved.

Comment: Just wondering:  Why do you ask this question?  What difference does it make to you?  You should know, for instance, that the internal algorithms for performing even rather simple integrals are frequently unrelated to the techniques we learned in high school and college.  Again:  Why ask?  The "facts" used may be extremely non-intuitive and non-obvious... but are used because they are computationally efficient.  (Please... no vacuous "just wondering" answer.)

Comment: @J.M.: Thank you for the references.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : I am working on proving that two integrals are the same. Mathematica apparently knows how to do that. I would like to know how Mathematica does it. If the proof is nontrivial, that is fine with me.

Comment: Well, you could execute a `Trace`, but I suspect that will be overwhelmingly complex, and hence of no value.

Comment: Maple finds `Sum[1 /(4^(3 m))  Binomial[2 m, m]^3, {m, 0, \[Infinity]}]` as a table value if I correctly understand the result of `printlevel := 20;
sum(binomial(2*m, m)^3/4^(3*m), m = 0 .. infinity);`.

Comment: Maple finds only the inner integral as a table value (see the result of `printlevel := 20;
int(int(1/sqrt(1 - sin(t)^2*sin(s)^2), s = 0 .. 1/2*Pi), t = 0 .. 1/2*Pi);
`).

Comment: `infolevel[all] := 5:` confirms the above comment of me.

Comment: @user64494 : Thank you for your comments. What do you mean by "table value"? (I don't have or know Maple.) (The inner integral is not a problem.)

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Something similar to Gradshtein&Ryzhik implimented in commands of Maple.

Comment: @user64494 : Is it possible to find references for these implementations?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: These implementations are made in the inner code of Maple.

Answer (score 3):

a partial answer:
From the defining integral for EllipticK[1/2]

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[1 - t^2]*Sqrt[1 - t^2/2]), {t, 0, 1}]
```

you get (along Borweins reasoning) with the (clever) substitution

```
Sqrt[u] == t^2/(2 - t^2)
```

to

```
(Sqrt[2]/4)*Integrate[1/(u^(3/4)*(1 - u)^2^(-1)), {u, 0, 1}]
```

which is equal per definition to

```
(Sqrt[2]/4)*Beta[1/4, 1/2]
```

and can then be expressed through Gamma functions.

Edit:

Another bit...

The binomials in the sum can be expressed (FunctionExpand) as gamma functions. The resulting sum can be seen as series expansion of

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}, 1]
```

like given in http://functions.wolfram.com/07.27.06.0002.01
again after function expanding the Pochhammer symbols.

This special value of the hypergeometric function is connected to EllipticK[1/2]^2 through its integral representation, but I did not succeed in fully understanding the result of the double integral

```
(1/Pi^2)*Integrate[
(1/Sqrt[(1 - t)*t])*(1/(Sqrt[(1 - s)*s]*Sqrt[1 - s*t])), {t, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

which Mathematica is able to calculate in two steps (first t, then s).

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer.